# How to make CustomPaint srollbar in flutter

Tags: flutter, custom-painting

I used this solution for drawing page in my app via CustomPaint
https://medium.com/flutter-community/drawing-in-flutter-using-custompainter-307a9f1c21f8

I wonder how to make the drawing space scrollbar in all directions because I need more space to draw in same page, not only the screen size. Is that possible? how to do it?

Thanks
Best regards

Comment: check `ScrollbarPainter`

Comment: @pskink do you have any example for it? I did not found example in the web. Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/400608f101/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/scrollbar.dart#L1188

Comment: this is a flutter git, is there any real example for ScrollbarPainter with CustomPaint